# React Native - Which module do you use to make in-app payments?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I develop a game app to drink with React Native and ExpoKit so without authentication, I wanted to know if I wanted to make a monthly payment how I could know if the person had paid or not? AsyncStorage? Or develop a back end? Or to use Stripe as back end? And which module is the most recommended to be able to develop a payment with Apple Pay & Google Pay? I have test : https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe but I don't success to import StripeModule for iOS and also https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments but that doesn't work)

Answer (score 2):

You can use react-native-iap.

https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap

And here are some medium articles about that.

https://medium.com/dooboolab/react-native-in-app-purchase-121622d26b67?
https://medium.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap-v3-1259e0b0c017

In here you could find, product and subscription. You can make a subscription in both android and ios. Also, you could send the result to backend after the user subscribes.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The back end is necessary or I can make this without back-end and use AsyncStorage ?

Comment: Use asyncstorage for what?

Comment: You can find getPurchaseHistory in the react-native-iap which returns the transaction list.

Comment: To save the date of end subscription if the user uses the app offline maybe?

Comment: I recommend react-native-sqlite-storage but the worst thing is that sqlite file could be removed when you reinstall the app.

Answer (score 2):

The way i have integrated in-app purchase is by following this article on medium which precisecly described how to integrate both on ios and android with ease. 
But keep in mind i've used bare react native ,i.e not expo. and i would recommend you to use pure react native for such complex functions.

[RN -IAP](https://medium.com/@abhayg772/implementing-in-app-purchase-in-react-native-application-3798ca2de5bb)

But if you wan to use expo , ive checked this on expo docs, hope it helps ::
[expo -in app purchase](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/)

And you would need a backend so that you can store the users after succesfull transactions. Hence backend is required.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts,

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! 
I will try with RN-IAP, I would have liked not to use Expo but I almost finished the app I would just like to remove Expo and keep React Native. I made an expo eject normally it's as if I had more than React native.